# Getting a 403 Forbidden when going to a URL with PhantomJS

Tags: phantomjs, user-agent, http-status-code-403

If I go to the following web page in Chrome, it loads fine: https://www.cruisemapper.com/?poi=39

However, when I run the following PhantomJS script, which simply goes to the same URL and outputs the entire DOM string to the console, I get a 403 Forbidden message:

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    url = 'https://www.cruisemapper.com/?poi=39';

page.open(url, function (status) {
    if (status === 'success') {
        console.log(page.evaluate(function () {
            return document.documentElement.outerHTML;
        }));

        phantom.exit();
    }
});
```

Here's the exact output to the console:

```
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /
on this server.<br>
</p>

</body></html>
```

I thought that if I added some sort of user agent string, it might work. As such, I added the following above the console.log line:

```
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36';
```

But that didn't work. So then I tried the following instead:

```
page.customHeaders = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'
};
```

But that didn't work either. Does anyone have any advice on how I can possibly hit up the URL above and not get a 403 Forbidden message? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me fine (I's suggest viewport size emulation though, see code). If you still get a 403, try changing your IP, it's possible that the site is on to you now (you probably visited that page lots of times).

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    url = 'https://www.cruisemapper.com/?poi=39';

page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36';

page.viewportSize = { width: 1440, height: 900 }; // <-- otherwise it's 400x300 by default

// It's good to watch for errors on the page
page.onError = function (msg, trace) 
{
    console.log(msg);
    trace.forEach(function(item) {
        console.log(' ', item.file, ':', item.line);
    })
}

page.open(url, function (status) {

    console.log(status);
    page.render("page.png"); // Also useful to check if you get what you expect

    if (status === 'success') {
        console.log(page.evaluate(function () {
            return document.documentElement.outerHTML;
        }));

        phantom.exit();
    }
});
```

Comment: Great answer. Thank you, Vaviloff. I'll play around with this later and mark the answer as correct if it all works well. How can I go about changing my IP address? Do I need to send that as another header? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't change IP with headers — you'd need a proxy or you could run this script on a remote (virtual) server, like on AWS, Digital Ocean, Vultr or any *lowend box* really.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks again.

Comment: Worked like a charm. The key was moving the page.settings.userAgent assignment to before the page.open method. I had it within the method. My bad. Thanks.